# Xcode 5.1 additional SDKs does not work when building for an iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I use a third party SDK and i set the path in "Additional SDKs", when i build for iOS Device the build failed because the SDK headers aren't found, it works fine when i build for the simulator.

Looking at the build log i see that when building for simulator -isystem is set with the path of the SDK include directory, but the option is not added when building for the device.

That used to work with Xcode 5.0 and Xcode 4.x any ideas of changes to "Additional SDKs" that could explain that?

Regards,
Jose

Comment: Any screenshot would be helpful..

Comment: I'm having issues with an "additional sdk" that cropped up when I upgraded to xcode 5.1. Not working for the simulator or device.